# Ошибка при переиндексации битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Нужно по крону запускать обновление карты сайта, для этого сперва надо запустить переиндексацию, делаю это так

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '900000');
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
define('NO_KEEP_STATISTIC', true);
define('NOT_CHECK_PERMISSIONS',true);
define('BX_CRONTAB', true);
define('BX_NO_ACCELERATOR_RESET', true);
define('SITE_ID', 's1');

require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/module.php");
CModule::IncludeModule("search");
$_POST['action'] = 'sitemap_run';
$_POST['ID'] = '1';
$_POST['value'] = '';
$_POST['pid'] = '';
$_POST['NS'] = '';
$_POST['sessid'] = bitrix_sessid();

//print_r($GLOBALS);
$NS = false;
$NS = CSearch::ReIndexAll(false, 0, $NS);
while(is_array($NS)) {
    $NS = CSearch::ReIndexAll(false, 0, $NS);
}
```

И получаю ошибку

```
Line: 1310
MySQL Query Error: UPDATE b_search_content SET UPD='f172684da9551267969df2693f32b7e5' WHERE ID = 1[[1205] Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction]
```

в SQL wait_timeout установлен на 90000

Comment: 1. А какого типа таблицы в базе? InnoDB или MyISAM? Если MyISAM, то в них блокировка при транзакции идёт на уровне таблиц, и другой процесс может вызвать блокировку.
2. И не может ли процесс переиндексации запуститься ещё раз, пока предыдущий не завершился, и вызвать блокировку?

Comment: @ВикторКарев запрос show table status возвращает в колонке engine InnoDB

Comment: Сколько времени идёт переиндексация? С какой периодичностью она запускается?

Comment: @ВикторКарев секунд 30 скрипт работает, потом ошибка, в кроне его нет

Comment: Зарегистрированы ли в системе дополнительные модули? Может быть, у них в обработчике события OnReindex используются транзакции? Можно попробовать переиндексировать не всё сразу, а по отдельному модулю, проверяя, на каком модуле будет вылет.